# Facebook image not displayed in share

Tags: facebook, share

I'm trying to publish on FB a link of my wife-website.

The [Open Graph Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Felenaborrione.it%2Fempatia-animale%2F) says that everything is fine (there is **og:image** tag and the image is 1200x630).

But the image isnt' displayed in the post, even if I try to scrape again the page!

Please, help me!
Riccardo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was confirmed by FB not so long ago... 
see: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/978421888869140/

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm this issue also occurs on multiple sites I own. It began some time in the past 14 hours. The debugger is returning a valid output (but the post preview at the bottom is lacking the image).

My guess is that it is somehow related to the face that today (30/apr) they've forced all fb apps to migrate to sdk2.0.

I sure hope they're already working on a fix... but go figure :-/

Comment: OK.. so it's a FB problem... not just a problem of my Wordpress install or plugin...

Comment: Just a question. You are writing about FB apps. I'm talking about a website. Is still the same thing? I need to do something on my WebSite?